# Displaying only 3 lines and deleting old ones

Tags: pine-script

The script is working pretty but in terms of performance it doesn't delete the lines in the past, which means it will probably crash when a lot of new candles appear on the screen. That's what I'm trying to solve.

How do I make it display only 3 lines and delete the old ones? Something like the one below, but I don't know exactly how to accomplish it. I know I have to do it with an array, but not sure how.

```
numberOfLines = 3

var label[] lbls = array.new_label()
var line[] lns = array.new_line()

if array.size(lns) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(lns) - 1
        if i > numberOfLines
            line.delete(array.remove(lns, i))
```

## Original code

```
//@version=5
indicator("RSI Market Structure display only 10", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 500, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500)

// ———————————————————— Constants {
// ————— Colors
var color GREEN         = color.green
var color RED           = color.red
var color BLUE          = color.blue
var color YELLOW        = color.yellow

// ————— Constants used in inputs
var string SHOW = "Show"
var string HIDE = "Hide"
var string SHOW_TODAY_ONLY = "Show Today Only"

// ———————————————————— Inputs {
// ————— Market Structure
var GRP1 = "Market Structure"
bool zigZagStructureInput = input.string(SHOW, "Show?", inline = "10", options = [SHOW, HIDE], group = GRP1) == SHOW
int zigZagLengthInput = input.int(7, "Length", inline = "10", group = GRP1)
color zigZagBullishColorInput = input.color(GREEN, "", inline = "11", group = GRP1)
color zigZagBearishColorInput = input.color(RED, "", inline = "11", group = GRP1)
color zigZagColorInput = input.color(BLUE, "Zig Zag", inline = "11", group = GRP1)
// }

// ———————————————————— Market Structure {
// RSI value based on inbuilt RSI
rsiValue = ta.rsi(close, zigZagLengthInput)

// Get the current state
isOverbought = rsiValue >= 80 // overbought level
isOversold = rsiValue <= 20 // oversold level

// State of the last extreme 0 for initialization, 1 = overbought, 2 = oversold
var int lastState = na

// Highest and Lowest prices since the last state change
var hh = low
var ll = high

// Labels
var label labelll = na
var label labelhh = na

// Swing lines
var line line_up = na
var line line_down = na

// We go from overbought straight to oversold  NEW DRAWINGS CREATED HERE
if zigZagStructureInput
    if lastState == 1 and isOversold
        ll := low
        labelll := label.new(bar_index, low, style = label.style_circle, color = zigZagBullishColorInput, size = size.tiny)
        labelhh_low = label.get_x(labelhh)
        labelhh_pos = label.get_y(labelhh)
        line_down := line.new(bar_index, high, labelhh_low, labelhh_pos, color = zigZagColorInput, width = 2)
    
    // We go from oversold straight to overbought NEW DRAWINGS CREATED HERE
    if lastState == 2 and isOverbought
        hh := high
        labelhh := label.new(bar_index, high, style = label.style_circle, color = zigZagBearishColorInput, size = size.tiny)
        labelll_low = label.get_x(labelll)
        labelll_pos = label.get_y(labelll)
        line_up := line.new(bar_index, high, labelll_low, labelll_pos, color = zigZagColorInput, width = 2)
        
    // If we are overbought
    if isOverbought
        if high >= hh
            hh := high
            label.set_x(labelhh, bar_index)
            label.set_y(labelhh, high)
            line.set_x1(line_up, bar_index)
            line.set_y1(line_up, high)
        lastState := 1
        
    // If we are oversold
    if isOversold
        if low <= ll
            ll := low
            label.set_x(labelll, bar_index)
            label.set_y(labelll, low)
            line.set_x1(line_down, bar_index)
            line.set_y1(line_down, low)
        lastState := 2
        
    // If last state was overbought and we are overbought
    if lastState == 1 and isOverbought
        if hh <= high
            hh := high
            label.set_x(labelhh, bar_index)
            label.set_y(labelhh, high)
            line.set_x1(line_up, bar_index)
            line.set_y1(line_up, high)
        
    // If we are oversold and the last state was oversold, move the drawings to the lowest price
    if lastState == 2 and isOversold
        if low <= ll
            ll := low
            label.set_x(labelll, bar_index)
            label.set_y(labelll, low)
            line.set_x1(line_down, bar_index)
            line.set_y1(line_down, low)
    
    // If last state was overbought
    if lastState == 1
        if hh <= high
            hh := high
            label.set_x(labelhh, bar_index)
            label.set_y(labelhh, high)
            line.set_x1(line_up, bar_index)
            line.set_y1(line_up, high)
            
    // If last stare was oversold
    if lastState == 2
        if ll >= low
            ll := low
            label.set_x(labelll, bar_index)
            label.set_y(labelll, low)
            line.set_x1(line_down, bar_index)
            line.set_y1(line_down, low)
// }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it doesn't delete the lines in the past, which means it will probably crash when a lot of new candles appear on the screen

Not really the case; Pine has an automatic garbage collector that deletes oldest lines dynamically when new ones appear specifically for performance. So strictly speaking, you don't need to do any cleanup by yourself unless you specifically want to. If you do:

At max Pine can leave around 500 lines on your chart, which in this script is indicated via the `max_lines_count=500` parameter in the `indicator` function. The easiest limit to implement is just setting `max_lines_count=3` (note that it won't be exactly 3, but around 3).

The better way is via arrays. It's easier to use the built-in `line.all` variable that returns an array with all lines on the chart:

```
lineLimitInput = input(3)
if array.size(line.all) > lineLimitInput
    for i = 0 to array.size(line.all) - lineLimitInput - 1
        line.delete(array.get(line.all, i))
```

Using `line.all` is better for your script than having a separate array because you don't have to push the new lines in there or remove the old ones after deleting them from the chart.

EDIT: if you want to use a separate array, the logic is also fairly straightforward: push a new line, check if the array goes over limit; if it does, remove the first line from the array and then delete it:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_lines_count = 500)

l1 = line.new(bar_index[10], high[10], bar_index, high) // Ignored lines
l2 = line.new(bar_index[10], low[10], bar_index, low, color = color.green) // Culled lines
l2LimitInput = input(3)

var l2Array = array.new_line()
array.push(l2Array, l2) // Push each new line into array after drawing it

if array.size(l2Array) > l2LimitInput
    // Note: removing the line from the array does not delete it from the chart, and deleting it from the chart does not remove it from the array.
    // Both these things need to be done separately.
    firstLine = array.remove(l2Array, 0) 
    line.delete(firstLine)
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwer! I understand, but `line.all` is not a solution to me, because this is not the only indicator in that script, there are boxes, more lines, more labels, etc. It means that I need a manual solution because if I change `max_lines_count` to 3, it will restrict my other indicators in that script and for ex. I have implemented FX Market Sessions indicator into mine. It has boxes, labels and lines. If I do that overall restriction, it will affect it all.

Comment: Updated with an example using a separate array, it might help